# Can't purchase a commitments GCP and edit quotas

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I purchase commitment this error is displayed.
Quota 'COMMITMENTS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region asia-southeast1.

I tried to edit quotas commitment but the checkbox is disabled.
My account is not a trial account and has about 3 months of payment history.
[image: quotas checkbox disabled]